# Apache Curator loses all watches after reconnection

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

I am using Apache Curator in my project. After CuratorFramework loses connection to the ZooKeeper server, it automatically reconnects, but it seems that it loses all the watches that I have set up, and I am not getting any notifications anymore. Watches work as expected if the connection is not dropped and restarted.

Is this is a Curator bug or am I doing something wrong?
The code for setting the watch is as follows:

```
CuratorFramework framework = CuratorFrameworkFactory.newClient(connectString, SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS, 0, new ExponentialBackoffRetry(CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MS, CONNECT_RETRY_COUNT));
framework.start();
framework.getChildren().usingWatcher(watcher).forPath(path);
```

thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `Watcher` should notify you if there is a change in the connection.  If so, the `EventType` on the `WatchedEvent` will be `None`, Use that as an opportunity to restart your watches:

```
@Override
public void process(WatchedEvent event) {
    if (event.getType == Event.EventType.None && event.getState() == Event.KeeperState.SyncConnected){
        framework.getChildren().usingWatcher(this).forPath(path);
...
```

Comment: I just stumbled across this question and wanted to add that in the current version (4.2.0) you can register ```ConnectionStateListener```'s to help with this exact behaviour [link](https://curator.apache.org/errors.html)